# Sending email with html tag via [UIApplication sharedApplication] on iPhone

Tags: iphone, email, uiapplication

I am trying to send an email with an embed code (html snippet) but the email body is empty.

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: me.emailUrl];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

        NSLog(@"SnapShotViewController->infoAction: %@", url);
```

The original string looks like this.

<iframe style='width:320px;height:320px;border:0px' src='http://snapserve.alphakanal.de/embed?key=b500bb47-e14d-405f-a70b-9779dbb8ce21'>

The final string looks like this.

mailto:?subject=SnapShot&body=%3Ciframe%20style%3D'width:320px;height:320px;border:0px'%20src%3D'http://snapserve.alphakanal.de/embed%3Fkey%3Db500bb47-e14d-405f-a70b-9779dbb8ce21'%3E%3C/iframe%3E

The email app opens up but does not show the body. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use `- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding` on your NSString containing the HTML, like so:

```
NSString *html = @"<html><body><b>test</b></body></html>";
NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?subject=SnapShot&body=%@",[html stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i am doing. See the final string in my first post. Thats the output of stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding. But the email is still blank.

Comment: Well, http://snapserve.alphakanal.de/embed?key=b500bb47-e14d-405f-a70b-9779dbb8ce21 is blank. So what exactly do you expect?

Comment: It is not blank. It returns a valid html page. But thats not what i wanted to show in the email. The user should see the actual <iframe> tag as text to be able to copy it to his website;